# Method for changing URL of page with a form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

This is probably a very simple issue for a developer, but I'm new to coding and am just looking for a solution to achieve the following.

I would like to create a single form field into which users type in the last segment of a URL (which will be provided to them)

When they type in this last segment, the page refreshes and takes them to the completed URL with the final segment that they entered.

Here is a visual example of what I am trying to achieve - but not sure of the best way to code a form that will do this seemingly simple task.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6FyS.png)

1. The single field form would be present on domain.com/client/
2. User types 'my-page' and submits the form
3. Page refreshes and user arrives at domain.com/client/my-page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Join the two strings together (or multiple strings) then use curl to open the url

```
<?php
$string1 = 'http://www';
$string2 = '.example.com/';
$url = curl_init($string1.$string2);
curl_exec($url);
?>
```

here is a more complete example using header location as another option instead of curl - you have the html and php here

```
<form action="" method="post">


Last part of url <input type="text" name="url"><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">


<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{
    $string1 = 'www.cambodia.me.uk/';
$string = $_POST['url'];

    header('Location: http://www.cambodia.me.uk/'.$string);
}
?>
```

Comment: did you test it - no. because it wont work. http://ideone.com/5iuJy8

Comment: @nogad - works on my server try it out at www.cambodia.me.uk/openurl.php maybe you can vote me back up again

Comment: `curl_exec()` "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure. "

Comment: you also need to have php installed - anyway not interested in bickering, like I said it works and i tested it first, i am going to see if I can help any other users - I want to be constructive not negative - cheers gonad

Comment: read what the OP asked, this is not what he wanted. "Page refreshes and user arrives at domain.com/client/my-page"

Comment: Thanks Kerry, really appreciate the assistance. If I read it right $string1 would be (in my scenario) 'http://www.domain.com/client/' which is the same in all situations, and then the client inputs $string2 (eg. peter) into the form field and submits, resulting in the reloading of the page at the created URL of www.domain/clients/peter

Comment: @ Matthew Symonds Yeah - I am just posting an update to the answer with some code that may help

Comment: @nogad so you know what he wants, you know php, why spend so much time being negative - why not just give him an answer ?

Comment: @kerry, I cannot thank you enough for your help here. I have successfully implemented your solution and you can see the work in progress here.

http://marlenephotography.com/index.php/clients

Enter 'kerry' in the field for it to work out :)

Such an elegant solution. THANK YOU!!!